# Typeorm one to many relation & tree

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, typeorm

Hello I have **Post** entity:

```
@Entity()
export class Post extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  title: string;

  @OneToMany(() => Comment, (comment) => comment.post)
  comments: Comment[];
}
```

and **Comment** entity:

```
@Entity()
@Tree('closure-table')
export class Comment extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @Column({ type: 'text' })
  body: string;

  @TreeParent()
  parent: Comment;

  @TreeChildren()
  children: Comment[];

  @ManyToOne(() => Post, (post) => post.comments)
  post: Post;
}
```

Posts have One To Many relation with Comments & Comments have tree relation.

I wanna fetch comments of post with id of 1 with tree relation, but don't know how to do it!

I can fetch comments in tree way but couldn't fetch post comments with tree style.